# Application Title Localization in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I would like to localize my app's title for Android. Someone suggested that this works by creating strings.xml under Plugins/Android/res/values-(language letter code) for each language. Maybe this was previously working but it does not seems to work in Unity 2019. Whenever I create a directory under res, the build fails. Can someone help me ?

Comment: Can you include the error it fails with?  It should be in your console.

Comment: Hi Eddge, the error was just a build failed with an exception that says I can't have a folder like that. I then saw this post from unity: https://support.unity3d.com/hc/en-us/articles/115005875443-Providing-Android-resources-in-Assets-Plugins-Android-res-is-deprecated

Answer (score 1):

I've realized that Unity build only fails if there is a directory called values. This folder is probably generated automatically by Unity during build and I had it there for some stupid reason. Actually having other language directories do not conflict.